# "Ho visto Laura" e "L'ho vista"

Tags: word-usage, past-participle

Ho da sempre questo interrogativo: perché nel primo caso il participio passato non si coniuga e nel secondo sì?
La forma verbale è la stessa, il significato pure, in un caso il complemento oggetto è "Laura" e nel secondo è "la", ma grammaticalmente dovrebbero essere la stessa cosa, credo.
Tanto più che il primo caso si avrebbe anche se usassi un pronome, purché lo metta dopo il verbo: posso dire "Ho vistO lei che usciva" oppure, nella seconda forma "l'ho vistA che usciva".

Suppongo che dipenda dalla particella prima del verbo (per esempio, posso dire "Ho lettO dieci dei suoi libri", o "ne ho lettI dieci"). 
Ma non riesco a trovare una spiegazione "formale", né so se questo abbia un nome.

Qualcuno sa illuminarmi sulla questione?
Grazie.

Comment: La concordanza si può fare anche nel caso ”Ho vista Laura“, ma non si usa da tempo. La differenza sta nella posizione del nome o pronome rispetto al participio: se è prima, il participio si concorda.

Comment: Intanto puoi dare un'occhiata [qui](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/accordo_%28Enciclopedia-dell%27Italiano%29/), a partire da “Più complicata, e se vogliamo instabile...”.

Comment: Grazie mille @DaG, link molto interessante.

Comment: La regola è quella dell'accordo del participio. Ho trovato questa sintesi di un articolo di Serianni per l'Accademia della Crusca: http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/it/lingua-italiana/consulenza-linguistica/domande-risposte/accordo-participio-passato. Tenendo conto delle oscillazioni d'uso, L'accordo, volendo semplificare molto, serve per far capire a cosa ci si sta riferendo. In «Ho visto Laura» l'oggetto è chiaro («Laura»), in «L'ho vista» la "a" finale dice che l'oggetto (citato prima di questa frase) è femminile singolare.

Answer (score 2):

Questa è probabilmente una delle regole meno chiare della grammatica italiana, almeno a giudicare da quante discussioni ho sentito al proposito. Ottimi riferimenti sono già stati dati da DaG ([Enciclopedia Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/accordo_%28Enciclopedia-dell%27Italiano%29/)) e da Benedetta ([Accademia della Crusca](http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/it/lingua-italiana/consulenza-linguistica/domande-risposte/accordo-participio-passato)). Li raccomando a chi voglia un'analisi più approfondita ché non ho né il tempo né le competenze per effettuare.

Ecco qui invece un riassunto delle regole per l'accordo del participio passato con i verbi che usano l'ausiliare **avere**, pur con tutte le sue limitazioni ed inesattezze, nella speranza che possa essere utile a qualcuno.

L'accordo del participio passato quando l'ausiliare è *avere*, è determinato dalla posizione e forma del **complemento oggetto**:

- Nel caso in cui il complemento oggetto sia una delle particelle pronominali ***lo***, ***la***, ***le***, ***li*** o ***ne*** preposta al verbo, il participio va **accordato** alla particella pronominale. (Con altri pronomi nella stessa posizione, l'accordo è opzionale: “ci ha visto” o “ci ha visti”.)
- In tutti gli altri casi (verbo intransitivo, privo di complemento oggetto, seguito da un complemento oggetto, preceduto da un complemento oggetto che non sia una delle cinque summenzionate particelle pronominali), il participio è nella forma "neutra", vale a dire il **maschile singolare**.

**Esempi:**

- *L'orco ha mangiat**o** Gianna in un solo boccone*
- *L'orco l'ha mangiat**a** in un solo boccone*
- *Il cane li ha annusat**i** ben bene*
- *Francesca ne ha vist**e** tante* (qui il *ne* sta per un implicito *cose*)
- *Il fidanzato non le ha più telefonat**o** per il resto della giornata* (da notare che qui, anche se il pronome *le* è anteposto al verbo, ha funzione di complemento di termine e non di complemento oggetto, per cui non vi è accordo)
- *I pellegrini hanno camminat**o*** (qui *camminare* è un verbo intransitivo con ausiliare avere, per cui non c'è nessun accordo, al contrario di *I pellegrini sono spariti*, dove l'ausiliare è *essere* e c'è accordo con il soggetto)

Da notare che a queste regole vi sono numerose (e complesse) eccezioni, ma per questo vi rimando alle risorse già consigliate sopra.

Comment: Non riesco a inserire le due spiegazioni dei miei edit: ne salva solo una :-/

Comment: @Benedetta Per favore, invece di reinserire ciecamente le modifiche che avevo già rimosso, possiamo discuterne nei commenti? Il termine "maschile singolare" non ha niente di sbagliato, tanto che è usato in uno dei due riferimenti. Inoltre non capisco perché insistere che questa regola si debba applicare solo ai verbi transitivi, quando invece l'ho scritta volutamente perché si applichi a tutti i verbi con l'ausiliare *avere* (inclusi gli intransitivi, come *dormire*)

Comment: Va benissimo, figurati! Come ho segnalato, non riesco a inserire le spiegazioni complete. Dunque, il verbo "dormire" non è intransitivo in casi come: "Quante ore hai dormito?" "Ne ho dormite tre". Inoltre, se consideri come potenziali verbi con cui fare l'accordo quelli che hanno l'ausiliare "avere", rientra nella casistica anche "telefonare", che però non è transitivo e con cui non usi quei pronomi. Lo, la, li, le (e anche mi, ti, ci, vi), nonché il partitivo ne sono pronomi diretti, vengono quindi usati con i transitivi.

Comment: Per quanto riguarda il participio passato, non si può dire che sia "maschile singolare". Diventa tale, in un certo senso, quando si accorda con il pronome diretto che lo precede. Il participio passato, in quanto tempo verbale, non ha genere e numero. Semplicemente, finisce con la vocale -o. Altrimenti, dovremmo dire che "ma" è femminile singolare…

Comment: Forse *dormire* non è l'esempio più adatto, ma [esistono verbi intransitivi con l'ausiliare avere](http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/en/italian-language/language-consulting/questions-answers/ausiliare-verbi-intransitivi). Nel caso di *telefonare* la particella pronominale non è un complemento oggetto, ma un complemento di termine, per cui la regola sopra non si applica. Per il secondo argomento, il participio passato si declina, mentre *ma* è indeclinabile. Non mi è chiaro perché un tempo verbale non possa avere anche un genere e un numero, a patto che sia declinabile.

Comment: @Benedetta, certo che il participio passato può essere maschile singolare: “Il participio è un modo verbale non finito che partecipa da un lato alla categoria dei nomi, di cui segue la flessione distinguendo numero, genere e caso; dall'altro...” ([Grammatica italiana Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/participio_%28La-grammatica-italiana%29/)).

Comment: @Denis Nardin: non sono verbi intransitivi che hanno l'ausiliare avere: sono verbi che a seconda della costruzione hanno l'ausiliare essere o l'ausiliare avere. Ad esempio, il verbo finire: "La lezione è finita alle dieci" (uso intransitivo, ausiliare essere); "Non ho finito i compiti" (uso transitivo, ausiliare avere). A mio parere, se non spieghiamo che questo accordo si fa solo quando ci sono i pronomi diretti o il ne, si crea confusione in chi, da straniero, non ha un uso quotidiano della lingua.

Comment: @DaG: il participio si flette nell'accordo o in quei casi che lo avvicinano a un uso aggettivale, quando diventa maschile, femminile, singolare o plurale a seconda dei casi. Se diciamo che può flettersi, uno straniero pensa che sia possibile dire: "Laura e Paola hanno mangiate".

Comment: @Benedetta Senza offesa, ma hai letto il link nel mio commento? Esempi lì presenti includono *ho vagito*, *ho puzzato*, *ho camminato* a fianco dei più ambigui *ho corso* e *ho straripato*. A me pare di aver scritto chiaramente che l'accordo si fa solo con i pronomi che hanno la funzione di complemento oggetto. Detto questo, sei più che libera di scrivere una tua risposta se l'impostazione di questa ti sembra ambigua.

Comment: @Benedetta ho aggiunto un po' di esempi.

Comment: @Benedetta: il participio ha una flessione analoga a quella nominale (numero e genere); poi, quando si accordi e con cosa, è un altro paio di maniche, che viene affrontato concisamente in questa risposta. Non c'è alcun dubbio che nella frase “Laura e Paola hanno mangiato”, “mangiato” sia maschile singolare: la questione da chiarire è perché lì si usi il maschile singolare anziché il femminile plurale o altro.

Comment: @Denis Nardin: ho letto, e torno a dire che secondo me la questione è l'uso transitivo o meno e non l'ausiliare "avere", visto che con "ho vagito" non c'è eventualità di fare l'accordo. Stiamo cercando di contribuire a un'unica risposta soddisfacente, almeno è quello che io cercato di fare. Non mi interessa fare le gare :-)

Comment: @Benedetta Non capisco l'obiezione allora. Se siamo entrambi d'accordo che con i verbi intransitivi in cui l'ausiliare è avere non c'è accordo, che problemi ci sono se lo aggiungo alla risposta? Per essere chiari, questa regola prescrive *I bambini hanno vagito* invece di *I bambini hanno vagiti* (che sarebbe la forma corretta se tutti i verbi intransitivi facessero l'accordo con il soggetto). Anzi, adesso la aggiungo agli esempi.

Comment: @Denis Nardin: trovo che sia più chiaro dire che l'accordo si fa con i verbi transitivi o usati in modo transitivo, perché l'accordo è tra participio e complemento oggetto espresso da un pronome diretto. Se scriviamo "l'accordo del participio passato con i verbi che usano l'ausiliare avere", poi dobbiamo specificare che ci sono alcuni verbi con cui non si fa e mi sembra più complicato… Poi, consideriamo che il participio si accorda al soggetto solo se l'ausiliare è "essere". Come hai giustamente scritto, questa concordanza è assai complicata.

Comment: A me sembra molto più semplice dire che l'accordo è deciso dall'ausiliare e dal complemento oggetto. Essere transitivi o intransitivi non ha niente a che vedere con ciò e secondo me è una falsa pista.

Comment: @Denis Nardin: Se per te l'ausiliare e il complemento oggetto non hanno a niente a che vedere con i verbi transitivi o usati in modo transitivo, non posso aggiungere altro :-) Grazie, comunque, dello scambio.

Comment: @Benedetta Più che "non hanno niente a che fare", direi che sono influenzati dall'essere o meno transitivo, ma che alla fine della fiera per l'accordo contano solo i risultato di questa influenza e non l'origine. Grazie anche a te per lo scambio e spero che le modifiche che ho fatto abbiano almeno indirizzato alcuni dei tuoi dubbi riguardo a questa risposta.

Comment: Mi sembra che Benedetta abbia nettamente ragione su entrambi i punti, ma forse essendoci un disaccordo a monte è più semplice scrivere un'altra risposta. Questa non è Wikipedia.

Comment: Sul merito n° 1: l'accordo riguarda verbi usati in modo transitivo, mi sembra una cosa facile da capire se spiegata così, mentre dire che riguarda alcuni verbi con l'ausiliare _avere_ ma non tutti non è una gran spiegazione.

Comment: Sul merito n° 2: anch'io ho sempre saputo che il participio passato "neutro" non è maschile singolare, ha solo la stessa forma. Non vedo perché confondere la spiegazione dicendo che una cosa è maschile singolare senza essere né maschile né singolare. Più facile dire che finisce per _-o_.

Comment: @MauroVanetti (1) Adesso smetto di scrivere commenti, ma l'accordo riguarda solo *alcuni* verbi transitivi, non tutti (quelli per cui il complemento oggetto è una delle particelle pronominali etc. etc.); per cui non vedo la differenza. Ripeto, essere transitivi o meno ha solo una influenza indiretta sulle regole dell'accordo. (2) Questa che il participio passato neutro non è maschile singolare non l'avevo mai sentita; e la grammatica Treccani almeno sembra concordare con me. In ogni caso, due buone risposte sono meglio di una...

Comment: @DenisNardin (1) Certo, l'accordo è obbligatorio o facoltativo a seconda di altri criteri, ma riguarda solo i verbi usati in modo transitivo. Quando è facoltativo la scelta non è tra accordo o maschile singolare bensì tra accordo o non accordo (quindi "neutro" che finisce in _-o_).

Comment: @DenisNardin (2) Proprio la grammatica Treccani (il link che hai fornito) dice che il participio passato può funzionare anche come verbo; in tal caso è invariabile. Se è invariabile non è maschile singolare.

Comment: Mi sembra che ci sia un certa confusione fra “maschile singolare” e “concordato con un termine maschile singolare”. Non c'è dubbio che “mangiato” sia una parola di genere maschile e di numero singolare, dovunque e comunque sia usata. Per fare un altro esempio, nelle concordanze a senso, se dico “furono viste un sacco di stelle”, “viste” e “stelle” sono al femminile plurale, “sacco” è maschile singolare, e la deroga alle norme sull'accordo può essere formulata *proprio* perché ognuna di quelle parole ha chiari connotati morfologici. Altrimenti non si potrebbe proprio parlare di accordo.

Comment: Invariabile, @MauroVanetti, non significa necessariamente “privo di genere e numero”; può significare, come qui, “che ha un genere e numero fissi, indipendentemente dal contesto”. Infatti l'unica menzione del concetto di “invariabile” nelle due pagine Treccani citate dice testualmente “si va affermando la tendenza al participio invariabile, al *maschile singolare*” (corsivo mio). Siamo tutti d'accordo (pun intended), adesso?

Comment: @DaG Ovviamente sono questioni non sostanziali, ma secondo me non ha nessun senso dire che in _Le navi hanno viaggiato_ la parola _viaggiato_ è maschile singolare. Non riesco proprio a capire in che modo è maschile e in che modo è singolare. Serianni citato dalla grammatica Treccani sbaglia, se il frammento è citato in modo non fuorviante. Comunque direi che ci siamo capiti.

Comment: @MauroVanetti: Per non intasare i commenti, [ho scritto in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65711/maschile-singolare) qualcosa sull'argomento. Non brillo per concisione, temo...

Comment: @Benedetta, MauroVanetti Aggiungo solo un'altra osservazione che mi è venuta in mente stamattina: nei verbi transitivi alla diatesi passiva l'accordo del participio si fa con il soggetto. Questa è un'altra indicazione che quello che conta per l'accordo è l'ausiliare e non se il verbo sia transitivo o intransitivo (a meno che voi non diciate che un verbo alla diatesi passiva sia "usato in senso intransitivo" che secondo me è una complicazione inutile)

Comment: @Denis Nardin: se rimaniamo al fulcro della domanda (perché dico "ho visto Laura" e "l'ho vista", se sostanzialmente sto dicendo la stessa cosa? È un altro regola?), la risposta è che si applica l'accordo del participio passato con il pronome diretto (cioè con l'oggetto). Quelli che stai citando sono altri casi e riguardano più in generale il vasto tema della concordanza o dell'accordo. Esistono quindi certamente casi in cui il participio si accorda con il soggetto, *non* con l'oggetto, ma sono casi in cui l'ausiliare è "essere" ed esulano dalla domanda posta.

Comment: @Denis Nardin: intendevo "È una regola?" (Ma non posso editare il commento).

Comment: @Benedetta Non credo che siamo in sostanziale disaccordo. Fondamentalemente ho deciso di dare una risposta che mettesse l'esempio della domanda in quello che credo sia il suo contesto naturale (l'accordo del participio nei tempi composti dei verbi che usano l'ausiliare avere). Non credo di aver scritto niente di falso, se ritieni che una risposta da un punto di vista diverso possa essere più chiara, assolutamente scrivine una. Come ho già detto più (buone) risposte ci sono, meglio è.