# Verbi transitivi con l'ausiliare essere

Tags: grammar, verbs, auxiliary-verb

Questa domanda mi è sorta mentre riflettevo sulla discussione relativa a [quest'altra](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/8550/ho-visto-laura-e-lho-vista).

La regola semplicistica per la scelta dell'ausiliare che viene solitamente insegnata ai bambini è che i verbi intransitivi prendono l'ausiliare essere, mentre i verbi transitivi (in diatesi attiva) prendono l'ausiliare avere.

In realtà la situazione è più complicata e ci sono alcuni verbi intransitivi che prendono l'ausiliare avere (*camminare*, *vagire*, ...), mentre altri verbi possono usare entrambi gli ausiliari (*correre*, *straripare*, ...). Non mi è chiaro però se esistano verbi transitivi con l'ausiliare essere e, ammesso che esistano, come si coniugherebbe la diatesi passiva per questi verbi.

> **Q:** Esistono verbi transitivi che usano l'ausiliare essere in diatesi attiva? Se sì, come si forma la diatesi passiva per essi?

Comment: Non me ne viene in mente nessuno e dubito che ne esistano. Ma l'italiano può nascondere recessi curiosi.

Comment: @egreg Sono nella stessa situazione. Ho provato a cercare conferma in alcune grammatiche, ma non ne ho trovata nessuna che dicesse esplicitamente che tutti i verbi transitivi hanno l'ausiliare avere, da cui la domanda...

Comment: Mi viene in mente solo “che ti è preso?” Vedi http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/prendere/

Comment: @egreg Sfortunatamente *ti* in *Che ti è preso?* è complemento di termine e non oggetto (come si può vedere da *Che gli è preso?* e non **Che lo è preso?*)

Comment: Dal libro *Grammatica dell'italiano adulto* di Vittorio Coletti, parlando della scelta tra *essere* e *avere* come ausiliari: «L'ausiliare del passivo è sempre *essere* ed  *essere* è anche  l'ausiliare dei verbi pronominali. *Avere* è l'ausiliare dei verbi transitivi, mentre...».

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, nell'italiano standard moderno non ci sono verbi transitivi che per formare i tempi passati usino il verbo “essere”.
Riporto il paragrafo XI.32 dell'*Italiano* di Luca Serianni:

> ***Ausiliari propriamente detti***
>   Si tratta essenzialmente dei verbi *essere* e *avere*, che consentono la formazione dei verbi composti con valore di passato rispettivamente: *a*) per la maggioranza dei verbi intransitivi [...]; *b*) per tutti i verbi transitivi e per un certo numero di intransitivi [...]
>   La scelta dell'ausiliare non comporta dubbi di sorta con i verbi transitivi (gli ausiliari *essere* e *avere* sono da sempre in distribuzione complementare rigida per indicare rispettivamente la diatesi passiva e il tempo passato) [...], almeno nell'italiano moderno.

Answer (score 0):

Magari dico una bestialità, però mi pare che quando si usa un verbo transitivo come riflessivo l'ausiliare sia sempre essere:

- Mi sono lavato le mani
- Ti sei fatto male

etc.

Comment: Per essere vero è vero, ma io intendevo un verbo transitivo in diatesi attiva. Hai ragione però, devo correggere la domanda.

Comment: Hai ragione, persson. Nel brano dal Serianni che riportavo nella mia risposta i riflessivi (insieme agli intransitivi pronominali come “mi sono accorto”) erano menzionati nelle parti che ho espunto, ma forse per chiarezza avrei fatto meglio a lasciarle.